# Robot Framework - check if element defined by xpath exists

Tags: python, testing, xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm wondering, I'd love to find or write condition to check if some element exists. If it does than I want to execute body of IF condition. If it doesn't exist than to execute body of ELSE.

Is there some condition like this or is it necessary to write by myself somehow?

Comment: you can write a conditional statement using the results of `Get Matching XPath Count` or `Get webelement` or `Get webelements`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By locating the element using xpath, I assume that you're using `Sselenium2Library`. In that lib there is a keyword named:

`Page Should Contain Element` which requires an argument, which is a `selector`, for example the xpath that defines your element.

The keyword failes, if the page does not contain the specified element.

For the condition, use this:

`${Result}= Page Should Contain Element  ${Xpath}
Run Keyword Unless  '${RESULT}'=='PASS'  Keyword args*`

You can also use an other keyword: `Xpath Should Match X Times`

Comment: thank you very much, I'm pretty new in Selenium so this is very helpful!

Comment: This only works for me when I try like this:

`${Result}=     Run Keyword And Return Status     Page Should Contain Element  ${Xpath}
Run Keyword Unless  ${RESULT}
`

The result should be False Or True

Comment: Remember to give more than one space between keyword and equal sign

Answer (score 7):

I prefer using Get Matching XPath Count since the accepted answer throws error if element is not found

```
${count}= Get Matching XPath Count ${Xpath}
Run Keyword And Return If   ${count} > 0 Keyword args*
```

Comment: Deprecated. Use Get Element Count instead. Refer https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Matching%20Xpath%20Count

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same doubt, but above answers doesn't satisfy what I wanted to

so,I used **rpaframework** library

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Browser.Selenium

*** Tasks ***
Verifying if a link is present or not
    Open Available Browser    https://www.amazon.com
    ${val}    Does Page Contain Link    //a[contains(@href,'some_text_present_in_your_link')]
    IF    ${val}== True
        Log    Link is present in the web page.
    ELSE
        Log    Link is not present in the web page.
```

There are many keywords present in this library to verify other things like elements, button, checkbox, image, textfield etc.

These keywords return True or False, so we can perform other steps based on variable value.

**Note:** Do not forget to install the rpaframework library.

```
pip install rpaframework
```

Comment: Wow, this is even better than SeleniumLibrary. Thanks for sharing.